# How to send from Gmail in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail, gmail-api

I am attempting to use the [Gmail Ruby Gem](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail) and I keep getting the following error:

```
Couldn't login to given Gmail account: foo@bar.com (Invalid credentials (Failure))
```

I am storing the `access_token` in my database using Omninauth. My method to authenticate with the gem looks like this:

```
def get_access_gmail(key)
  client = OAuth2::Client.new(KeyChain.google.key, KeyChain.google.secret, {
   :site => 'https://www.google.com'
  })

  auth_hash = {:oauth_token => key}
  access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.from_hash(client, auth_hash)

  return Gmail.connect!(:xoauth2, "foo@bar.com", access_token)
end
```

Where `key` is my saved `access_token`, that I got from Omniauth. I am using the proper scopes and I am sending the same email that I used to authenticate.

What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone tell me how to authenticate with this gem properly?

Note that I have also tried

```
def get_access_gmail(key)
  return Gmail.connect!(:xoauth2, "foo@bar.com", key)
end
```

EDIT:

I have also tried using the `google-api-client` gem from Google, to no avail. Following their docs [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby), I cannot figure out how to properly authenticate a user after already saving their `access_token` and `refresh_token` using Omniauth. Even if I were to get the gem authenticated properly, it doesn't seem like any documentation for that gem actually exists. Their API docs are just as bad.

Does anyone have any insight on how to use either of these gems properly? Google's docs are confusing and the unofficial Gmail gem doesn't seem to work at all with OAuth.